# Distributed Transaction management in Core Java application

Tags: java, jms, distributed-transactions

Is it possible to use distributed transaction manager in core java application which does not run inside any container?

I have an application which reads message from JMS queue and writes it to the database. If writing to the database fails then complete transaction should roll back. I am thinking of using JOTM, but not sure how to configure it. Also not sure if that kind of configuration is possible at all, as the application does not run in any server. Any suggestion will really be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been writing servers in *core* Java for more than 14 years and you can do this with a little coding in plain Java.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It will really be helpful if you can provide me a sample for the same.

Comment: I tend to write code to do this, but not for about 5 years.  However JMS can be set to be transactional, and you decide whether to commit() or not a message.

Answer (score 1):

This [Spring blog entry](http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/) explains how to configure JTA outside of container.  JOTM is one of the options described.

For your case, it would be simpler to just use ChainedTransactionManager to simulate JTA. You get nearly the same effect with minimal Spring configuration.  Configure as below, and then specify `@Transactional(value="chainedTransactionManager")`on your listener.

```
@Bean 
JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    JmsTransactionManager manager = new JmsTransactionManager();
    manager.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return manager;
}

@Bean 
JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    return manager;
}

//Encapsulating TM used to commit/rollback JMS and JPA together, without overhead of JTA.  Note that JMS should be listed first, as transactions commit in reverse order and JMS less likely to fail.
@Bean 
ChainedTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager(JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager, JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager){
    ChainedTransactionManager manager = new ChainedTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager, jpaTransactionManager);
    return manager;
}
```

Comment: user392909, Earlier I have used distributed transaction management using JOTM in Spring. But here we are not using Spring. That means we don't have any container. I wanted to know if there exists any way to handle distributed transaction (with the help of JOTM or any any other tool) if the application is not running inside any container.

Comment: Ah sorry, misread the question and haven't done what you ask before.  Probably would start with Atomikos though and not JOTM, as seems to be more widely used and more recently updated.  Here is an example: http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTransactionsEssentials#Simple_JTA_example